# php mysql insert query is populating every column with the same values

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, foreach

I am developing a class for a site that has a lot of mysql querys. The idea of the class is to make it easier ans more unified. The class works but on the insert query it fills every column with the last data entry of the array.

Here is my function:

```
public function insert($table, $values){

         $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (";
         $x = 0;
         $vals = "";
         foreach($values as $col => $val){
             $sql .= ($x < (count($values) - 1)) ? $col.", " : $col." ";
             $vals .= ($x < (count($values) - 1)) ? "?, " : "? ";
             //$vals .= ($x < (count($values) - 1)) ? $val.", " : $val." ";
             $x++;
         }
         $sql .= ") VALUES (".$vals.")";
         $stmt = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
         $x = 0;
         foreach($values as $col => $val){
             //echo 'bindParam('.($x + 1).', '.$val.', PDO::PARAM_INT);';
             $stmt->bindParam(($x + 1), $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
             $x++;
         }
         //print_r($stmt);
         $stmt->execute();
         print_r($stmt->errorInfo());    
     }
```

I have echoed out the sql which shows no errors:

> INSERT INTO accounts (first_name, last_name, email, address, post,
>   country, password ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )

And also the params, which again no error:

```
bindParam(1, john, PDO::PARAM_INT);
bindParam(2, smith, PDO::PARAM_INT);
bindParam(3, john@test.com, PDO::PARAM_INT);
and so on...
```

This is the outcome in the database:
[image: Database Error]

I cant seem to find where I have gone wrong with this but obviously somewhere i have. I greatly appreciate the help to fix this.

And this is how the function is called:

```
$this->insert('accounts', array(
                    'first_name' => $f_name,
                    'last_name' => $l_name,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'address' => $address,
                    'post' => $zip,
                    'country' => $country,
                    'password' => $pass
            ));
```

Called for a different table:

```
$this->insert('newsletter', array( 'name' => $f_name.' '.$l_name, 'email' => $email )
```

But this one works!!
//////// EDIT SOLVED /////////////////
The problem was the ->bindParam Loop, I switched it to this

```
public function insert($table, $values){

         $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (";
         $x = 0;
         $vals = "";
         $querys = array();
         foreach($values as $col => $val){
             $sql .= ($x < (count($values) - 1)) ? $col.", " : $col." ";
             $vals .= ($x < (count($values) - 1)) ? "?, " : "? ";
             array_push($querys, $val);
             $x++;
         }
         $sql .= ") VALUES (".$vals.")";
         $stmt = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
         for($x = 0; $x < count($querys); $x++){
             $stmt->bindParam(($x + 1), $querys[$x], PDO::PARAM_INT);
         }
         //print_r($stmt);
         $stmt->execute();
         print_r($stmt->errorInfo());    
     }
```

And it was works fine, not sure why but the foreach loop was causing the error

Comment: And when you dump for example $f_name right before the insert query, does it also give you the correct result?

Comment: MySQL’s utf8
 using MySQL’s utf8 charset for databases, tables, and columns, assuming it mapped to the UTF-8 encoding . By using utf8, You’d be able to store any symbol you want in your database

Answer (score 1):

I tried this script for testing:

```
function insert($table, $values){

     $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (";
     $x = 0;
     $vals = "";
     foreach($values as $col => $val){
         $sql .= ($x < (count($values) - 1)) ? $col.", " : $col." ";
         $vals .= ($x < (count($values) - 1)) ? $val.", " : $val." ";
         $x++;
     }
     $sql .= ") VALUES (".$vals.")";
     var_dump($sql);
 }
 insert('accounts', array(
                'first_name' => "f_name",
                'last_name' => "l_name",
                'email' => "email",
                'address' => "address",
                'post' => "zip",
                'country' => "country",
                'password' => "pass"
        ));
```

This just creates the query. I initially got your error too, and it was because the single variables `$f_name`, `$l_name`were `NULL`. The script above works perfectly, so your problem is in the vars you use as parameters of the method.

Comment: Yeah it was the params causing the problem, Ive added the bit i changed to the question. Thanks